# How to get instagram media by hashtag using api?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am pretty confused why instagram returning only how many media only hashtags have but not the actual pics .I want to get media with hashtag

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats?access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

it returns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Instagram Graph API

Comment: Could you be more specific because i feel like their documentation is pretty vague